# TFS Build process template: In Console app, executing Console.Writeline fails build

Tags: tfs, console-application, tfsbuild

I have an TFS build with a Build Process Template (xaml) that calls a console application.  Whenever the console app returns messages, i.e. `Console.WriteLine("Starting Build")`, the build interprets this as an error and tfs marks the it as 'Partial Failure'.

How can I return a message to the build log from a console app that does not cause the build to fail?  Should I look at another way to return messages from the console app that will display in the build log?  Or do I have to use an external logging method such as writing to a database / log4net etc.

[image]

Update: The workflow I am changing was not using the InvokeProcess.  I corrected this, and am getting an error message displayed and the build still fails.  You can see below I am attempting to write the error as a "WriteBuildError" and "WriteBuildMessge".  Only the WriteBuildError displays, and the build still fails.  What am I missing?

```html
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess DisplayName="InvokeProcess" FileName="[&quot;&quot;&quot;C:\app.exe&quot;&quot;&quot;]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="InvokeProcess_3" Result="[ExitCode]">
  <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="errOutput" />
      </ActivityAction.Argument>
      <mtbwa:WriteBuildError sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="WriteBuildError_9" Message="[&quot;Handle Error Build Error: &quot; + ErrorMessage]" />
    </ActivityAction>
  </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
  <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="stdOutput" />
      </ActivityAction.Argument>
      <Sequence DisplayName="Handle Output" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_40">
        <Assign sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Assign_3">
          <Assign.To>
            <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[ErrorMessage]</OutArgument>
          </Assign.To>
          <Assign.Value>
            <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[If(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage), Environment.NewLine + ErrorMessage, "") + stdOutput]</InArgument>
          </Assign.Value>
        </Assign>
        <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="WriteBuildMessage_6" Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High]" Message="[&quot;Build Message: &quot; + ErrorMessage]" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces"
        />

        <mtbwa:WriteBuildError sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="WriteBuildError_10" Message="[&quot;Build Error: &quot; + ErrorMessage]" />

      </Sequence>
    </ActivityAction>
  </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CodeActivity for logging. Description here: [Send information to the build log](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-8-Send-information-to-the-build-log.aspx)

Comment: If I read this article correctly, this is using a Build Process Template.  However i have a custom console app.  It is called from the build template, however it is a stand alone console app.  I don't have the context (CodeActivityContext) as there is no 'Execute' method, only the console app "Main(...)" method.  How can I get the context?

Answer (score 0):

It's based off of the application's exit code. It's not the message that's causing the error, it's because the application is exiting with a code that isn't 0.

Comment: Are you saying it is as simple as setting Environment.ExitCode = 0; before I call Console.WriteLine?

Comment: I'm saying that the application is failing and exiting with a non-zero exit code. It has nothing to do with `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: No, the application is not failing. As the command line executes (it is a long running process) messages such as "I am starting now" are written to the console via WriteLIne() and are displayed in the activity loq. They are displayed as some sort of failure as they have the red X next to them. Whenever the build shows a message, the build fails.  If I remove the WriteLine statements, the build does not fail.